# Add shadows on tableviewcell while reordering

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How do I add the same shadow effect on the left and right sides of the selected cell when reordering?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps some code examples at least?

Comment: you can decrease cell width slightly on selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a solution using a Tableview. i think this is a limitation in tableviews. A workaround is using a collectionView instead of a table view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the shadow only on left and right, then inset the rectangle on the top and bottom so the top and bottom shadow are hidden behind your view:

```
CGRect shadowRect = CGRectInset(someView.bounds, 0, 4);  // inset top/bottom
someView.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowRect] CGPath];
```